# How to change array indexes in php?

Tags: php

```
array(
      [0]=>1
      [1]=>2
      [2]=>3
      [3]=>4
)
```

If delete second element, you have

```
array(
      [0]=>1
      [2]=>3
      [3]=>4
)
```

Now how to change indexes to

```
array(
      [0]=>1
      [1]=>3
      [2]=>4
)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to re-index your array starting to zero, simply do the following:

```
$myNewArray = array_values($myOldArry);
```

Comment: But this requires multiple calls and is less than desirable... using array_splice would probably be the best way to go.

Answer (score 2):

From the php docs:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php

> array_splice: Removes the elements designated by offset and length from the input array, and replaces them with the elements of the replacement array, if supplied.

So, you would use:

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4);
array_splice($arr, 2, 1); //Will give you an array: [1, 2, 4]
```